# python IDLE 3.8.4 not saving files

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, python-idle, python-3.8

today when i tried to do a problem where there was  2 userdefined functions in the script mode and when  i tried to save it ,
the dialoque box for saving comes up and i fill in the name then press save but then the dialoque box just closes and the file still remains as * untitled *

this was the code

```
import csv
def addCsvFile(username,password):
    f=open("user.csv","w")
    newfilewriter=csv.writer(f)
    newfilewriter.writerow([username,password])
    f.close()

def readcsvfile():
    with open("user.csv","r") as newfile:
        newfilereader=csv.reader(newfile)
        for row in newfilereader:
            print(row[0],row[1])
    newfile.close()


addCsvFile(“Arjun”,”123@456”)
addCsvFile(“Arunima”,”aru@nima”)
addCsvFile(“Frieda”,”myname@FRD”)
readcsvfile()
```

when i removed any one of the code for  addCsvFile() or readcsvfile() and tried to save it ..it got saved

i saw a similar issue here for the same version as mine - https://bugs.python.org/issue41329

where i tried to save it was c drive/documents

my python idle version is 3.8.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IDLE 3.8.4 and 3.9.0b4 won't save files with non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000314/idle-3-8-4-and-3-9-0b4-wont-save-files-with-non-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000314/idle-3-8-4-and-3-9-0b4-wont-save-files-with-non-ascii-characters/63008021#63008021), either add `import io` at the top of `<pythondir>/idlelib/iomenu.py` or, if you can, upgrade to 3.8.6, which has other bugfixes both in IDLE and the rest of Python.

Comment: thank you terry jan reedy .sorry for the late response : )